# MydatabaseAdapter not working

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

Hye. Im new in android programming. Now Im developing an application like a MP3 application. So here is my code. But I got a lot of errors in logcat. I wanna know where is the errors.

```
    package com.aino.hafazan;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;


    public class MyDatabaseAdapter {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Surah";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH = "surah";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT = "count";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // surah related columns    
    public static final String SURAH_NAME ="surah_name";    
    public static final String NO_OF_VERSE = "no_of_verse";
    public static final String SURAH_ID ="surah_id";
    public static final String HIGHEST_VERSE_ID_FK = "highest_verse_id_fk";


    // count related colums
    public static final String SURAH_ID_FK = "surah_id_fk";
    public static final String VERSE_NAME = "verse_name";
    public static final String COUNT = "count";
    public static final String HIGHEST_VERSE_ID = "highest_verse_id";


    private static final String TAG = "MyDatabaseAdapter";


    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SURAH =
        "create table IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH + " (" + SURAH_ID + " integer primary key, "
        + SURAH_NAME + " TEXT not null," + NO_OF_VERSE + "integer not null," + HIGHEST_VERSE_ID_FK + 
        " INTEGER REFERENCES COUNT(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID);";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_COUNT =
            "create table IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT + " (" + SURAH_ID_FK + " integer REFERENECE SURAH(SURAH_ID), "
            + VERSE_NAME + " TEXT not null," + COUNT + "integer not null," + HIGHEST_VERSE_ID + 
            " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);";


    // Context of the Activity that is using this database

    private final Context mCtx;
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    public MyDatabaseAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }


    public MyDatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    // Database helper class
    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SURAH);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_COUNT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH);
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT);
                onCreate(db);
            }
            else
            {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH);
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT);

            }
        }
    }

    public void SaveData(SQLiteOpenHelper mDb)
    {
           SQLiteDatabase db = mDb.getWritableDatabase();

           ContentValues val = new ContentValues();

           //TABLE SURAH AL FIL
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "105");
           val.put(SURAH_NAME, "AlFil");
           val.put(NO_OF_VERSE, "5");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH, null, val);

           //TABLE COUNT AL FIL
           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1051");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL FIL VERSE 1");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "105");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);  

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1052");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL FIL VERSE 2");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "105");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);


           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1053");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL FIL VERSE 3");
           val.put(COUNT,"count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "105");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1054");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL FIL VERSE 4");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "105");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1055");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL FIL VERSE 5");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "105");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);


           //TABLE SURAH QURAISYH
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "106");
           val.put(SURAH_NAME, "Quraisyh");
           val.put(NO_OF_VERSE, "4");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH, null, val);

           //TABLE COUNT QURAISYH
           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1061");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "QURAISYH VERSE 1");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "106");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1061");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "QURAISYH VERSE 1");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "106");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1061");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "QURAISYH VERSE 1");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "106");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1061");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "QURAISYH VERSE 1");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "106");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);


           //TABLE SURAH AL MAOON
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "107");
           val.put(SURAH_NAME, "Al Maoon");
           val.put(NO_OF_VERSE, "7");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH, null, val);  

           //TABLE COUNT AL MAOON
           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1071");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL MAAON VERSE 1");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "107");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1072");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL MAOON VERSE 2");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "107");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1073");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL MAOON VERSE 3");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "107");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1074");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL MAOON VERSE 4");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "107");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1075");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL MAOON VERSE 5");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "107");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1076");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL MAOON VERSE 6");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "107");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID, "1077");
           val.put(VERSE_NAME, "AL MAOON VERSE 7");
           val.put(COUNT, "count");
           val.put(SURAH_ID, "107");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, null, val);

           val.put(SURAH_ID, "108");
           val.put(SURAH_NAME, "Quraisyh");
           val.put(NO_OF_VERSE, "4");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH, null, val);   

           val.put(SURAH_ID, "109");
           val.put(SURAH_NAME, "Kafirun");
           val.put(NO_OF_VERSE, "4");
           db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH, null, val);

           db.close(); // Closing database connection   

    }

    public int count(int count, int surah_id)
    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COUNT, "count");
        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE_COUNT, cv, SURAH_ID + "= " + surah_id, null);  


    }




    /**
     * Close database
     */
    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*public Cursor fetch_Surah_By_Surah_Id(
            String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String sortOrder)
            {

                return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH, new String[]
                        {
                        SURAH_ID, SURAH_NAME, SURAH_SEQUENCE}, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

    }
    public Cursor fetch_Fil_By_Surah_Id(String surah_id, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

            Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_FIL, new String[] {
                SURAH_ID, 
                FIL1_IMAGE,
                FIL2_IMAGE,
                FIL3_IMAGE,
                FIL4_IMAGE,
                FIL5_IMAGE,
                FIL1_AUDIO,
                FIL2_AUDIO,
                FIL3_AUDIO,
                FIL4_AUDIO,
                FIL5_AUDIO
                },SURAH_ID + "=" + surah_id,null,null,null, SURAH_ID + "ASC", null);
            return mCursor;
    }
    public Cursor fetch_Quraisyh_By_Surah_Id(String surah_id, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

            Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_QURAISYH, new String[] {
                SURAH_ID, 
                QUR1_IMAGE,
                QUR2_IMAGE,
                QUR3_IMAGE,
                QUR4_IMAGE,
                QUR5_IMAGE,
                QUR1_AUDIO,
                QUR2_AUDIO,
                QUR3_AUDIO,
                QUR4_AUDIO,
                QUR5_AUDIO
                },SURAH_ID + "=" + surah_id,null,null,null, SURAH_ID + "ASC", null);
            return mCursor;
    }

    public Cursor fetch_Kauthar_By_Surah_Id(String surah_id, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

            Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_KAUTHAR, new String[] {
                SURAH_ID, 
                KAU1_IMAGE,
                KAU2_IMAGE,
                KAU1_AUDIO,
                KAU2_AUDIO,
                KAU3_AUDIO,
                },SURAH_ID + "=" + surah_id,null,null,null, SURAH_ID + "ASC", null);
            return mCursor;
    }*/

}

I really appreciate if you can help me because Im going to submit this end of this december. 

THIS IS MY LOGCAT ERRORS

    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711): Process: com.aino.hafazan, PID: 6711
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ";":  syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table IF NOT EXISTS surah (surah_id integer primary  key, surah_name TEXT not null,no_of_verseinteger not null,highest_verse_id_fk INTEGER REFERENCES  COUNT(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID);
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at com.aino.hafazan.MyDatabaseAdapter$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(MyDatabaseAdapter.java:75)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at com.aino.hafazan.MyDatabaseAdapter.open(MyDatabaseAdapter.java:63)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at com.aino.hafazan.Fil$5.onClick(Fil.java:101)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    11-21 12:32:00.729: E/AndroidRuntime(6711):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you show logcat error?

Comment: you can see your logcat message `SQLiteException: near ";":  syntax error (code 1)`. The cause is your SQL statement missing close parentheses. I think so!

Comment: I think you missing ')' at end and also not define no_of_verseinteger data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ')' at end to complete "(" which is started after database name :

```
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SURAH =
            "create table IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_SURAH + " (" + SURAH_ID + " integer primary key, "
            + SURAH_NAME + " TEXT not null," + NO_OF_VERSE + "integer not null," + HIGHEST_VERSE_ID_FK +
            " INTEGER REFERENCES COUNT(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID));";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually know the cause by reading you `Exception`. It says there that something is wrong with your SQL query string near `;` - looks like you forgot to add the closing parentheses in `DATABASE_CREATE_SURAH`.

Let me try to fix it for you:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS surah (surah_id integer primary key, surah_name TEXT not null,no_of_verseinteger not null,highest_verse_id_fk INTEGER REFERENCES COUNT(HIGHEST_VERSE_ID));
```